# Unable to create PNS credentials in notification hub using PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-notificationhub

I am using the following JSON input file to create a new notification hub in PowerShell:

```
"Name": "my-tester",
"Location": "West US",
"Tags": {
    "tag1": "tag"
},  
"Properties": {
    "ApnsCredential": {
        "Properties": {
            "KeyId": "xxx",
            "Token": "xxx",
            "AppName": "xxx",
            "AppId": "xxx",
            "Endpoint":"https://api.push.apple.com:443/3/device"
        }
    },
    "GcmCredential": {
        "Properties": {
            "GoogleApiKey": "yyyy"
        }
    }
}
```

}

The PowerShell command is:
`$newHub = New-AzureRmNotificationHub -Namespace $nameSpace -ResourceGroup $resourceGroup -InputFile ".\$newHubName-HubProps.json"`

The command does create the hub ...but the PNS credentials are empty (I also verified from the portal). So when I inspect the 
newly created hub using this PowerShell, I get nothing. Here is the PowerShell command:
`$newHubPnsCreds = Get-AzureRmNotificationHubPNSCredentials  -Namespace $nameSpace -ResourceGroup $resourceGroup -NotificationHub $newHubName`

`# This returns nothing:
$newHubPnsCreds.GcmCredential`

Any help is appreciated.

Regards